# How to process value from for loop in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have to a perform logic like this.
I have a array.
expression for this in shell

```
[(first no + arrlen) - ( index +1 ) - ge 10 ]
```

I have code this like this but it's not working

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(4 5 6 7 8 9)
for i in ${array[@]}
do
echo $i
done
echo "${#array[@]}"
l=${#array[@]}


    count=0
    for (( i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; i++ ))

     do
       if [ ($(`expr $i + $l`) - $(`expr ${!array[@]} + 1`)) -ge 10 ]
            then
            count=`expr $count + 1`
            else
            echo
       fi
    done
```

Comment: anyone can help me out.

Comment: try this : if [ $(($(`expr $i + $l`) - $(`expr ${!array[@]} + 1`))) -ge 10 ]

Comment: it's not working

Comment: Can you add your array in the code ? So we can test the whole thing

Comment: yes ,i have added.

Comment: What is `first no`? Maybe try to describe your problem, it might be easier done with a different logic.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

array=(4 5 6 7 8 9)
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done

length=${#array[@]}
first=${array[0]}
count=0
for (( i=0; i < length; i++ )); do
    if (( (first + length) - (i + 1) >= 10 )); then
        ((count++))
    else
        echo "something"
    fi
done
```

1. Don't use `expr`, use `(( ))` for arithmetic expressions
2. Quote expansions: `"$i"`, `"${array[@]}"`, ...
3. `${!array[@]}` expands to **ALL** indexes of your array, not the current index

Comment: fist no is 1st element of array and and since i need indexes in loop.

Comment: @uttam What exactly is not working? It does the logic you described.